# What is the meaning of ずれる on this sign?

Tags: meaning

I found the below sign in a [tweet about the new ordering system at Saizeriya](https://twitter.com/nokonk0/status/1673167450446389253). What puzzled me is the text on the sign at the bottom-left:

> 右側のイスにずれて、順番にお待ち下さい。
> Please wait in line by ???ing at the chair to the right.

Ignoring the poor English translation, what is the intended meaning of ずれる? [Looking it up in a monolingual dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%9A%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B/), I only see the meanings I know, which refer to being displaced from an intended position (with nuances of being wrongly in that new position).

What, then, does the sign mean by イスにずれて?

[image: Image of a sign at Saizeriya]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sign is asking you to "slide" or move along to the chair to your right as you move forward in the line.

Comment: I can see that this clearly corresponds to 元あったところから、少しすべり動いて移る. But would you say that you can use the verb _without_ the implication in the second part of the definition: 基準の位置に合わない状態になる?

Comment: @jogloran - Basically yes, but I feel a slight connotation of vacating the original place for the next (rightful) occupant.

Comment: @jogloran - I didn’t think it was strange at all, but some people seem to think this usage of ずれる as a volitional action verb itself (with any connotations) is weird. See [this](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1292403542). I agree おずれになる is wrong but 右にずれて seems OK. It may be dialectal. 右に詰めて does sound more formal.